# What is wrong with this construction of the real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

Define a real number $r$ to be

$$r = x + \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \dfrac{a_k}{10^k}$$

where $x$ is a nonnegative integer and $a_k \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$.   Denote the additive inverse of $r$ by $-r$.

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? You may want to specify that $a_k \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ to make it easier to work with.

Comment: Great. But it is valid if you have constructed rational numbers already. So that you can define this infinite series. Also you will have to prove alot of theorem to prove that this is an ordered complete field. It seems  the infinite series should be symbolic and some properties must be added as axioms.

Comment: In your case $\displaystyle \sup \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \dfrac{a_k}{10^k}=10$ which obviously happens when $a_k=9$ $\forall k$ so that bounds $r$. We have $r \leq x + 10 $  for any integer $x$.

Comment: Whoops... correction $\displaystyle \sup \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \dfrac{a_k}{10^k}=1$ and that makes $r \leq x + 1$ for any $x$.

Comment: Maybe you would like to take a look at the following page by Tim Gowers (Fields medal 1998):  https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/decimals.html

Answer (score 4):

Note that even if you restrict the $a_{i}$ to come from the set $\{0,1,..,9\}$ you will still encounter issues. Consider $r_{1}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{a_{k}}{10^{k}}$ versus $r_{2}=1+\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{b_{k}}{10^{k}}$ where $a_{i}=9$ for all $i$ and $b_{i}=0$ for all $i$. These two expressions represent the same real number yet are defined with different $x$s and $\{a_{i}\}$s. To 'well define' the real numbers you will have to take steps (like the traditional 'equivalence classes of Chaucy sequences') to quotient out such coincidences.

Answer (score 1):

If you confine $0\le a_k \le 9$ - nothing.

However, the definition is dependent on base 10, and various properties about limits/completeness need to be proved. I think Prof T Gowers has a note somewhere about how this works (couldn't find it immediately, to my shame).

The normal characterisations of the reals have been fine-tuned to the properties which seem to matter in further mathematical development. They can be shown to be equivalent (under appropriate conditions).

[Note Kaya's answer, which I know the aforementioned Prof Gowers has dealt with in his characteristically efficient fashion]

Comment: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/decimals.html

Comment: @ChrisEagle   Thanks. There is more at https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/mathsindex.html under analysis.